# Strange behavior with HasRequired

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-mapping

The help for `HasRequired` states

> Configures a required relationship from this entity type.
>                    Instances of the entity type will not be able to be saved to the database unless this relationship is specified.
>                    The foreign key in the database will be non-nullable.

I have a none required field configured like

```
public class BookingConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Booking>
    {
        public BookingConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(ai => ai.BookingKey);

            ...

            HasRequired(b => b.Customer)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal();

            ToTable("Booking");
        }
    }
```

This is ofcourse very strange since Customer is not required. But, it works :D Both for null values and when customer is set. If I change to

```
HasOptional(b => b.Customer)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal();
```

It fails with (Already at get from database)

> Invalid column name 'Booking_BookingKey'.

The code that fails

```
var existingBooking = await _context.DbSet<Booking>().FirstAsync(ai => ai.BookingKey == confirmCommand.BookingKey);
```

edit: Structure of entities are

```
public class Booking
{
   public Guid BookingKey { get; set; }
   ...
   public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
   public Guid BookingKey { get; set; }
   ...   
}
```

Comment: please, provide the structures of `Consumer` and `Booking`

Answer (score 0):

Since BookingKey is both the Key for Booking and the ForeignKey for Customer try setting the ForeignKey field during setup.

```
HasOptional(c => c.Customer)
     .WithOptionalPrincipal()
     .Map(m => m.MapKey("BookingKey"));
```

Comment: The only other thought I have is, should it be `WithOptionalDependant()` instead of `WithOptionalPrincipal()`? Can a Customer record exist without a Booking record?

Comment: No we have a constraint on that table to Booking

Comment: If a Customer requires a Booking then Booking is the Principal, not Customer. Can you try it with `WithOptionalDependant()` and see if that works? Might still need to set the foreign key name as well though. If it does I will update the answer.

Comment: The code is at the office will have to try tomorrow, but pretty certain I tried that